# I am using the ubuntu operating system. When I run the emulator in the Android studio, it waits for a long time and shuts down

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

Hello my name is Oguzhan, I have a problem, I am using ubuntu operating system. When I run the emulator in Android studio, it waits for a long time and shuts down.

This problem does not occur in Windows operating system. My computer has both windows and ubuntu installed (Dual Boot)

[https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/40228440/63114849-90684000-bf9e-11e9-9629-da341c1992a9.png here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tMtw.png)

[https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/40228440/63113708-ca841280-bf9b-11e9-8bb5-7cc2d0d2814c.png here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXvJa.png)

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/40228440/63114848-8fcfa980-bf9e-11e9-8e48-ccecf358e8e1.png

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/40228440/63114846-8fcfa980-bf9e-11e9-8a27-6fe5fb8130a9.png

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/40228440/63114845-8fcfa980-bf9e-11e9-901f-5ae4d985faa1.png

**build.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.grade Module**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu via a VM?  If so, that's the problem-  the emulator is a VM, and you can't run a VM in a VM using this technology.  If that's the issue, its unsolvable.

Comment: Hello Gabe Sechan , I installed ubuntu with dual boot method.

I didn't use the VM method.